# script is not woking

Tags: visualforce, jquery

I have tried jquery for check null input fields. But it is not working. What is mistake i made. any help?

```
    <apex:pageBlock title="Enter Information">

        <apex:pageBlockButtons location="bottom">
            <apex:commandButton value="Save" action="{!Save}" id="btn" />
            <apex:commandButton value="Cancel" action="{!Cancel}"/> 
        </apex:pageBlockButtons>

        <apex:PageblockSection columns="1">
            <apex:inputField value="{!Job_Application__c.Name}" />

            <apex:PageBlockSectionItem >
                <apex:outputLabel value="Preferred Email" />
                <apex:actionRegion >
                    <apex:inputField value="{!Job_Application__c.Preferred_Phone__c }" >
                        <apex:actionSupport event="onchange" reRender="Personal" /> 
                    </apex:inputField>
                </apex:actionRegion>
            </apex:PageBlockSectionItem>

        </apex:PageblockSection>

        <apex:outputPanel id="Personal">
            <apex:pageBlockSection rendered="{!Job_Application__c.Preferred_Phone__c == '1'}">
                <apex:inputField value="{!Job_Application__c.Home_Phone__c}" styleClass="rend" /> 
            </apex:pageBlockSection>

            <apex:pageBlockSection rendered="{!Job_Application__c.Preferred_Phone__c == '1'}">
                <apex:inputField value="{!Job_Application__c.Work_Phone__c}" styleClass="rend" /> 
            </apex:pageBlockSection>

            <apex:pageBlockSection rendered="{!Job_Application__c.Preferred_Phone__c == '1'}">
                <apex:inputField value="{!Job_Application__c.Other_Phone__c}" styleClass="rend" /> 
            </apex:pageBlockSection>

        </apex:outputPanel>

    </apex:pageBlock>

</apex:form>

                    <script type="text/javascript">
                                var matches = 0;
                                    $(".rend").each(function(i, val) {
                                      if ($(this).val() == null) {
                                      matches++;
                                      }
                                      if(matches > 2){
                                        alert('Only one field should be null');
                                      }
                                    });
                    </script>
```

Comment: "It's not working" : what does it mean ? Do you have any error message ?

Comment: What you are trying to do here?

Comment: You should include jQuery plugin!

Comment: Still it's not working.

Comment: Here i'm trying to count null value fields